# How do I discover the additional causes of my Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build-pipeline-plugin

When attempting to query a build using groovy, I call

```
myBuild.getCauses()
```

I can see in the interface of Jenkins (the build screen) that this build has two causes, a UserIdCause, and an UpstreamCause. However, when I interrogate the same build with the groovy above, I only get a single cause back, which is the UserIdCause. There must be some method of getting the UpstreamCause from the build, or it wouldn't be present in the user interface.

I am using the Build Pipeline plugin to manually trigger the builds.

Comment: I've since learned that the getActions() method on the Run gives you another angle to come at causes. I'll post a more complete answer to the question when my time limit has expired.

Comment: will be nice to post the sample causes in JSON/XML

Comment: I have the opposite problem: `thr = Thread.currentThread(); build = thr?.executable`; and then `build.getCauses()` returns only a single upstream cause. I'm using the Build Pipeline plugin to launch from manually, and want ti know which user clicked the build/rebuild icon but I can't get the UserId cause even though as you say it is shown in the Jenkins build screen

Answer (score 7):

Here is the working groovy code (I tried in jenkins script console) to use `build.getAction`

```
job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("demo-job")
build = job.getLastBuild()

// get action first
def action = build.getAction(hudson.model.CauseAction.class)
// get the list of causes
for (cause in action.getCauses()) {
    println cause.getShortDescription()
}
// another way to find specific UpsteamCause directly
cause = action.findCause(hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause.class)
println cause.getUpstreamRun()
```

See reference

1. see build-pipeline-plugin how to add cause in code [BuildPipelineView.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-pipeline-BuildPipelineView.javaplugin/blob/c3339ecf3a4b2e7514ce206dcc953bbed86d8b63/src/main/java/au/com/centrumsystems/hudson/plugin/buildpipeline/#L490)
2. see the [hudson.model.Cause API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.html)

Answer (score 7):

It appears that `build.getCauses()` does not get all causes, but only the causes of the first `causeAction` of `build.getActions(hudson.model.CauseAction.class)`, probably by calling `build.getAction(hudson.model.CauseAction.class)`

Additional actions with their own cause can be found with:

```
def actions = build.getActions(hudson.model.CauseAction.class)
```

and so we need to review the causes of *each* of those actions, so instead of `def causes = build.causes()` we have

```
def causes = build.getActions(hudson.model.CauseAction.class)
             .collect{ it.getCauses() }.flatten()
```

and in my case that will return a list something like:

```
[ 05b8ef62-d071-11e8-b9db-9fd4e0aedf12/job/MyView/1238[11ef1ed2-d071-11e8-8c81-b71616102fe9/job/MyJob/4250[hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@2ddf7e3e]],
  hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@3337c79c ]
```

Where the first member represents the build pipeline plugin `upstreamCause` and the second member represents the user who manually triggered this build.

Certainly I wish the [Build User Vars plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) would use the shallowest  `hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause`, and not from any upstream cause!

In like manner, there is no point in simply traversing the chain of `cause.upstreamCauses` because each upstream may have multiple causes.

Instead of recursing along `cause.upstreamCauses`, access `upstreamRun`'s cause actions using:

```
cause.upstreamRun.getActions(hudson.model.CauseAction.class).collect{ it.getCauses() }.flatten()
```

Note:

`build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause)` may return `NULL` where `build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)` will succeed, even when the there exists an action from `getActions()` whose cause is `Cause$UserIdCause`, so presumably `getCause` also calls `getAction()` instead of `getActions()`