# Can there be a few build causes in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The `currentBuild` global variable in Jenkins has a method of `getBuildCauses()`. The Reference says this:

> getBuildCauses
> Returns a JSON array of build causes for the current build

I was wondering, why does this method returns an array? Is there any possibility that a build was caused by several causes?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19000589/598141)

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where a job was triggered by another job that was e.g. started manually by a user. So this information about a user who triggered the parent job is made available in the array. In another case, this job may be rebuilt manually by a user from a previous run that was triggered by a webhook. Sometimes, people want to know the whole history of the job instance, and so it's made available in this array.